# Server based BitCoin wallets

Tags: bitcoind

Is there a Bitcoin wallet which can be installed server side with a direct access iOS/Android app to maintain the funds but where two different parties can access it directly.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help the site by posting back your comments as an answer and marking it as accepted so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use bitcoind: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind

and use the

the bitcoin json rpc api https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Comment: Thanks for the answer, allowed me to search and found you can setup an Electrum server which allows an Electrum client to connect to it, exactly what we were looking for.